# Javascript database trouble

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database, paypal

So I have successfully implemented paypal to my page but I need to know how to check if the payment was approved (which I have) and then changed their payed status in my database.

- payed = 0 : user has not bought service
- payed = 1 : user has bought service

  ```
           <div id="smart-button-container">
           <div style="text-align: center;">
               <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
           </div>
       </div>

       <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=myid&currency=EUR" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>

       <script>
           var payment_valid;
           function initPayPalButton() {
               paypal.Buttons({
                   style: {
                       shape: 'rect',
                       color: 'black',
                       layout: 'vertical',
                       label: 'paypal',

                   },

                   createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                       return actions.order.create({
                           purchase_units: [{"description":"Premium","amount":{"currency_code":"EUR","value":0.1}}]
                       });
                   },
                   //Need to insert something here into my database
                   onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                       return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                           alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!' + ' data:' + data);
                       });
                   },

                   onError: function(err) {
                       console.log(err);
                   }
               }).render('#paypal-button-container');
           }

           initPayPalButton();
       </script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To record payment status in your database, capture from your server via an API to get the success status. Do *not* use `actions.order.capture()` on the client side, since there is no guarantee of being able to record a successful capture on your server if you do that.

So, for a proper server integration, create two routes -- one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', as [documented here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls) Your routes should return/output JSON (and only JSON). The capture route should check for success after calling PayPal and do any database writing before returning JSON to the client.

Pair your two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server